# Reload firebase user every time user open apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an app where if I delete users from the console user still can access some information from the database. so I reload the user every time users open the apps on the splash screen.
My concern is if it is a good idea or not to reload user every time opening the apps?

this is my current code is,

```java
void reloadUserInfo() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null)
        user.reload().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    goToHome();

                } else {
                    Helper.customToast(Splash.this, task.getException().getMessage());
                    goToLogin();
                }
            }
        });
    else
        goToLogin();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reload the user"? Do you have code to share?  What do you think the problem might be?

Comment: @DougStevenson take a look at my code I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that there is a problem here.  If you're observing a specific issue, please post a question that describes what's not working the way you expect.